# stripe payment auto changing status in .Net core 6

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I have added stripe payment as an Identity folder in my project and I have two tables named OrderHeader and Orderdetails entities in my data base.I created a SD class which has some status and the default status is "Pending_Payment".this status should be updated to Submitted_PaymentApproved in database after placing order,but all of my orders save as Pending_Payment in database .As a result,when I definite to show the list of orderHeaders which are in Inprocess or Submitted status ,it doesnt show me any data but when I change it to pending status it shows.I want to know what should I do to update the status from pending?

```
public class ManageOrderModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _uniOfWork;
        public List<OrderDetailVM> OrderDetailVM { get; set; } 
        public ManageOrderModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _uniOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            
            OrderDetailVM = new();
            List<OrderHeader> orderHeaders = _uniOfWork.OrderHeader.GetAll(u => u.Status           ==SD.StatusSubmitted || u.Status == SD.StatusInProcess).ToList();
             
            foreach(OrderHeader item in orderHeaders)
            {  
                OrderDetailVM individual = new OrderDetailVM()
                {
                    OrderHeader = item,
                    OrderDetails = _uniOfWork.OrderDetails.GetAll(u => u.OrderId ==   item.Id).ToList()
                };
                OrderDetailVM.Add(individual);
            }
       
        }
       


    }
}
```

this is my view of my razor page block:

```
@page
@model PracticeWithVideo.Pages.Admin.Order.ManageOrderModel



<h1 class="text-primary py-3">Manage Order's</h1>
<form method="post">
    <div class="container row bg-white p-2 mb-3 rounded">
        @foreach(var item in Model.OrderDetailVM)
        {
            <div class="col-12 pb-3 pt-3 mt-4 border rounded">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        Order Number: @item.OrderHeader.Id
                        <ul class="text-info">
                            @foreach(var details in item.OrderDetails)
                            {
                                <li>@details.Name x @details.Count</li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 pb-2">
                        <div class="input-group pb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text bg-secondary border">Time</span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" value="@item.OrderHeader.PickUpTime" class="form-control" readonly />
                        </div>
                        <textarea readonly asp-for="@item.OrderHeader.Comments" class="rounded border form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3 offset-1 d-flex align-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12">


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control mb-3">
                                <i class="bi bi-check-square"></i> &nbsp; Start Cooking
                            </button>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control mb-3">
                                <i class="bi bi-emoji-laughing"></i> &nbsp; Order Ready
                            </button>


                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning form-control mb-3">
                                <i class="bi bi-x-square-fill"></i> &nbsp; Cancel Order
                            </button>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
            </div>
       
   
</form>
```

I change the

```
List<OrderHeader> orderHeaders = _uniOfWork.OrderHeader.GetAll(u => u.Status           ==SD.StatusSubmitted || u.Status == SD.StatusInProcess).ToList();
```

to

```
List<OrderHeader> orderHeaders = _uniOfWork.OrderHeader.GetAll(u => u.Status           ==SD.StatusPending ).ToList();
```

and it shows the data because all of my orders saved as Pending_payment in my database.I need to show change the status from pending to submitted after placing order and display the data when I run my project

Comment: do you have order with Submitted Data in tables?

Comment: no,all of my order status didnot change after doing payment successful in database